# Which Publicly Accessible Large Language Models are Very Similar to OpenAI's ChatGPT?

Tags: nlp, language-model, gpt

What other large language models exist or will soon exist that are VERY similar to OpenAI's ChatGPT in the sense of being fine-tuned or otherwise specifically created for conversational tasks including question answering? Such models can be free to use or require subscription. I'm preferably looking for models that can give companies API access. I am interested in models with fairly high quality question answering performance in terms of accuracy and not having too many "hallucinations".

Here are some examples I am currently familiar with:

- **InstructGPT** from OpenAI: https://openai.com/blog/instruction-following/
- **OpenAssistant** from LAION: https://github.com/LAION-AI/Open-Assistant
- **ChatSonic** from WriteSonic: https://writesonic.com/chat
- **Jasper Chat**: https://www.jasper.ai/chat
- **Google Bard** (Google's soon to be released rival to ChatGPT): https://blog.google/technology/ai/bard-google-ai-search-updates/
- **ChatGenie** via WriteCream: https://www.writecream.com/chatgenie/
- **YouChat** from you.com: https://www.you.com/chat
- **Perplexity AI**: https://www.perplexity.ai
- **Bing Chat** (literally uses ChatGPT): https://www.bing.com/

Answer (score 1):

Anthropic's Claude LLM:

- [API](https://docs.anthropic.com/claude/docs)
- [Web demo](https://claude.ai/)
- [Benchmark](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/42064/4)

Cohere LLM:

- [API](https://docs.cohere.com/)
- [Web demo](https://dashboard.cohere.com/playground/chat)